# In reactjs how can I get the response from fetch() in other file

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to retrieve data from database in server.

In **file A** I call `fetch(url)` then I expect to get the response in **file B**, is this possible?

Back then when I'm using *electronJS* this can be easily achieved by using `ipcRenderer.on('channel', function);`.

So in **file A** I fetch data using `ipcRenderer.send('channel', someData);` then I received the data in **file B** by declaring `ipcRenderer.on('channel', function(result));`.

Now I am not using electronJS because I plan to build a web app, from what I have learned I can get the data from database using `fetch(url)` but the problem is I don't know how to receive the data in other file.

let me know if you need more explanation.

**ADD EXAMPLE CODE:**

I get this example code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381103/9177853
similar problem but not exactly the same.

In **file A**:

```
export const getData = () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")
  .then(response => response.json())
```

In **file B**:

```
import { getData } from './path/to/getData.js';

const someFunc = () => {
   getData().then(data => {
       // set redux state
       this.props.setReduxState(data);
   })
}
```

But **file B** won't automatically listen to incoming `data` response thus store the data to redux state, without calling `someFunc();` explicitly.

What I want is just by calling `fetch(url)` on a button click in **file A**, **file B** is always ready to listen to incoming response then store the response data to redux store.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912931/how-to-make-common-api-call-function-using-fetch

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible, and it sounds like inter component communication, add sample code and hopefully you will get some help. You Component A (File A) to write into a `state` that Component B (File B) depends on.

**Update from your sample code.**

1. If your planning to use Redux: Please take a look at [redux action and reducer](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions).It requires some initial setup.
2. If your app is small I will suggest your look at react [hooks useReducer and useState.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)
3. You can use [the context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in react as well, if your app is relative small and you do not want to pass pros arrount.
4. And finally you might not need a state management tools at all. I will suggest you create a Root Component and store all your data in its state, and have its child Compoents update and comsume that state. This easily achievable with some reading. You can [check one my repo that does it here](https://github.com/morlombakop/react-devices-dashboard/blob/master/src/components/app/App.jsx)

Comment: in fact, I want to set the state (redux state) from component B, the main idea is I want to centralize all response from fetch() in one component mainly File B, because I have many fetch() call in my app, and if I have to set state from each file it will create many duplicate code

Comment: It is possible and it is a very common use case in react, add a sample code or a link to CodeSandbox, it is hard to help without seing any codes